# difference between element.classname and element .classname selectors in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I understand that a space between CSS selectors indicates nesting. For example, **.funny p** would select all paragraph elements within an element of the class "funny", and I would similarly (from this logic) expect **div .funny** to select all "funny" elements within a div tag. However, I never actually see nested selectors in that form in any documented examples, but see quite a bit of those in the form **div.funny**. Is this simply nice shorthand for what **div. funny** would convey, or is there in fact a subtle difference I'm missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`div.funny` Selects all divs that have the class `funny`

While

`div .funny` Selects all elements with the class `funny` that are descendants of a div.

The space makes a significant difference

Comment: To the anonymous downvoter, care to leave a comment as to what's wrong with this answer?

Answer (score -1):

`div.funny` in CSS would target a `div` with the class name of `funny`, which is also what you'd get if you were to use that as a jQuery selector.